# Element sessionID is undefined Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a test server and a live server of coldfusion. In both I have hosted the same project and  I am using the value of sessionid in both test and live server from session. But in live server ,surprisingly it is saying that sessionID is undefined in session. I have enabled the option "enable j2EE session variable" in cfadmin and the error is resolved. But I have analyzed the test server and found that sessionId is present in session without checking the option "enable j2EE session variable".. How can that be possible?

Comment: Have you enabled sessions on both servers in the Application.cfm/cfc file? Are you in fact using the exact same code on both servers?

Comment: yes session is enabled in both server and using same code in both server.

Comment: It would help if you post the code that you're using to do your test, and exactly what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if scope cascading (scope precedence) is turned off in your coldfusion admin panel. Look for 'scopes'. It depends on what CFML-engine you are running where to find it. Or you could just scope your variable, like: #session.sessionID#

I would recommend to always scope your variables, because: 
- Scope precendence does slow down performance as the server must cycle through the different possible scopes.
- Your code is more readable if you scope your variables correctly and you make less mistakes